# Getting NullReferenceException with Forms while running without debugging | No Exception if Debugging

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, nullreferenceexception

I want to refresh some programming skills and started a c# project with VS, .NET 7.0.
Even when I just want to compile this line of Code

```
Form form = new Form();
```

I get this

```
Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.AdjustWndProcFlagsFromConfig(Int32 wndProcFlags)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.get_WndProcFlags()
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.get_WndProcShouldBeDebuggable()
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.AssignHandle(IntPtr handle, Boolean assignUniqueID)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.AssignHandle(IntPtr handle)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

But when I run with debug, it does what it should.

May be important to know:
First of all I had to put a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll and installed System.Configuration.ConfigurationManger with NuGet.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Broda.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in a .NET 6.0+ project. That's the .NET Framework way of referencing Winforms, and you now probably referenced even the .NET Framework library (what exactly did you reference?)

Instead, add this line somewhere near the top of your csproj (in a `PropertyGroup` section):

```
<UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>
```

Comment: I just add a reference path: right click on your project -> add -> project reference -> Project -> Browse and add the \Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.dll

I tried yourt solution and deleted the reference and Im getting the error:
the type or namespace name could not be found
that I got before i added the reference.

Comment: @Broda Yea, that's what I assumed. That file is from .NET framework, which is technically very different from the .NET core based versions 5.0 and later. So remove that reference and add the line as indicated above. Of course, you can also just create a new .NET Winforms project. Make sure it does NOT say ".NET Framework" in the template description.

Comment: For my understanding, the reference I made is a reference to an older version?

Comment: I added <UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms> as you said, but that didn't solve the problem. But I changed <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework> to <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework> aswell and now its woking. But I don't know why.

Comment: That's because WinForms is only supported on Windows, so you need to tell the compiler that you're fine with using libraries/methods that are only supported on windows.